# Solr can't use two joins in one query

Tags: solr

I have a problem using two joins in one query. While this query returns nothing:

```
q={!join+from=a+to=b}text_stem_ascii:(text)^5 OR {!join+from=a+to=b}text:(text)^10
```

the following query (please note the missing joins) returns something:

```
q=text_stem_ascii:(text)^5 OR text:(text)^10
```

the fields `text` and `text_stem_ascii` always contain some data so it's not an issue of missing data.

Answer (score 1):

OK, me bad. When using joins the join needs to be specified only once! E.g.

```
q={!join+from=a+to=b}text_stem_ascii:(text)^5 OR text:(text)^10
```

Sorry for wasting your time!